# Prevent The Details Form From Openning If No Details, Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to prevent the details form from opening if their no details to display. It seems to work, but there is an extra annoying error 2501 that pops ups "**The openform action was cancelled**" when I close the custom error message.

I have this code on the details button on the parent form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEvent_Participants", , , "[Event_ID]=" & Me!txtEvent_ID
```

And in the open event of the details form I have this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

With Me.RecordsetClone
If .RecordCount = 0 Then
Beep
MsgBox "There are no records to view", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
Cancel = True
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the form you're *opening* that's generating the error, it's *the code or macro that's opening* the form, and the error can be avoided with basic error handling.

For example, if the form is called `Form1` and you're opening with code behind a command button (or whatever), with code like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
```

then wrap error handling around it like:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
On Error GoTo 0
```

---

Alternatively, depending on what the form's doing, you might want to be more careful, to make sure that the only error you're "ignoring" with `On Error Resume Next` is `Error 2501:The OpenForm action was canceled` then check for it:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
If Err <> 0 And Err <> 2501 Then Err.Raise Err, , Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: You can just do the error checking before the `On Error GoTo 0`, and raise it there. That saves you some lines of code (you do have to trust that no errors will occur when raising the error).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth right - not sure why I had it in my mind to do it that way.  Edited, thanks.  (Is there a simpler way to throw the existing error instead of `Err.Raise myErr, , myErrDesc`?)

Comment: Just `Err.Raise Err.Number, , Err.Description`. You can omit `Err.Description` for most errors, but you get less specific descriptions (for example, 2501 = Application-defined or object-defined error, which doesn't tell you a whole lot).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - oops, that's what I meant.. (still had my variables in there).  And `Err` is equivalent to `Err.Number`, correct?

Comment: Yup, `Number` is the default property, so that gets passed.  You use a user-defined functions for errors, which I often use, but that doesn't have access to the original error, so you need to pass the number and description. So that's not simpler, it just allows more control (like logging errors, sending error reports, triggering a debug mode or a simple mode).